# Export SAS .XPT File from C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sas

I want to export SAS .XPT file from C#.net

Is there any way i can do this?

Can it be possible to convert .CSV file to SAS .XPT file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the information you need.
[Record Layout for a SAS Version 8 or 9 Data Set in SAS Transport Format](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/movefile/67439/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0ld1i106e1xm7n16eefi7qgj8m9.htm)